# how to get Google Plus ID with a Google Authentication

Tags: php, api, openid, google-plus

I saw a website get the Google Plus Profile ID with Google OpenID authentification.
how was that done?

Answer (score 2):

This: http://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth should help.

Comment: You can't get access to the Google+ APIs using OpenID. You have to either use OAuth2Login: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login or the built-in features of the Google+ Platform.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/

Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 0):

now google+ is allowing it's users to get short Url..
Just goto the

> HOME->PROFILE->ABOUT..

You will be asked to set your URL. or check at the "Google+ URL" under the **LINKS**

Answer (score -1):

Might not be exactly what you want, but could create alternatives for others:

Try http://gplus.to/

Provide your nickname. desired ID (e.g. stewardjornsen)
current Google Plus ID. 111085298314325543215

Add and get the following url:

http://gplus.to/stewardjornsen

This is very much a redirect service, but would get the job of giving you a simple and manageable url done.

You can share that url... I really can't figure why google won't consider have simple ids like that easier: Facebook, Youtube (strangely, google) and Twitter all do that.